# Looking for a script to colorize C++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Does anyone know of a script to colorize C++ code the same as the default MSVC IDE does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the open source project [Highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/).

It's not a script-per-se -- but it is scriptable.  The nice thing is that it parses code and the style-sheet is very easy to customize colors, bold and italics, etc....

Answer (score 5):

If it's for the web I can recommend you [prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), it's the script that StackOverflow uses for code colorization, and it's really easy to get it working...

Answer (score 2):

Is [SyntaxHighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/) the sort of thing you're looking for? There is also [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/), which has been updated more recently.

Answer (score 1):

The in-browser http://tohtml.com/ syntax hilighter is pretty good, depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ is pretty good and I use it when I'm on a windows system and doing C++.

Here is the title off the sourceforge page:
Notepad++ is a generic source code editor (it tries to be anyway) and Notepad replacement written in c++ with win32 API. The aim of Notepad++ is to offer a slim and efficient binary with a totally customizable GUI.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/